# Convert XML to CSV (StartupInfo XML log file)

Tags: powershell

I would like to convert the StartupInfo XML log file (Windows 10) to CSV.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WDI\LogFiles\StartupInfo\<SID>_StartupInfo<NUMBER>.xml
```

I tried:

```
[xml]$StartupInfo = Get-Content "C:\Windows\System32\WDI\LogFiles\<SID>_StartupInfo<NUMBER>.xml"
$StartupInfo.StartupData.Process | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\<USER>\Desktop\StartupInfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

But I have still problems with the columns "CommandLine", "DiskUsage" and "CpuUsage".

Thx for assistance.

Comment: I am sure you have noticed that those three nodes contain multiple nodes each... How do you want to handle/display them?

Comment: CommandLine = C:\...
DiskUsage = 7269376
CpuUsage = 13831684

I would like to see only the entries.

Comment: Do you want to enter just the first of them in the csv or every subentry of CommandLine, DiskUsage and CpuUsage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there are more distinguished methods to do this like XSLT transforms. But for this particular type of XML file I think this method works:

```
$StartupInfo.StartupData.Process | Select-Object Name,PID,StartedInTraceSec,
    @{name='CommandLine';Expression={$PSitem.CommandLine.'#cdata-section'}},
    @{name='DiskUsage';Expression={$PSItem.DiskUsage.'#text'}},
    @{name='CPUUsage';Expression={$PSItem.CPUUsage.'#text'}} | 
        Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\<USER>\Desktop\StartupInfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is that XML files aren't flat like CSV files are. If you want an explanation of the technique I used have a look here: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx

Comment: Nice one +1, please notice that you can insert line breaks (even without a trailing backtick \`) where ever PoSh expects a continuation; after  a comma or a pipe so your code stays readable.

Comment: Thanks @lotpings. Wasn't sure how to break code over multiple lines in stackoverflow :-) So there's no 'how', just do it